# how do I find elements under svg tag : elements such as rect, g, ellipse

Tags: svg, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, ellipse

Below is the HTML details:

```
<svg class="fs-dynamic-layout-svg" width="767" height="448">
  <path class="edge dragline hidden" d="M0,0L0,0">
  <defs>
  <rect class="pop-rectangle STATE_INIT" x="10" y="20" width="363.5" height="184">
  <rect class="pop-rectangle STATE_INIT" x="393.5" y="20" width="363.5" height="184">
  <rect class="pop-label-bg STATE_INIT" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" style="fill: rgb(20, 185, 173); stroke: rgb(20, 185, 173); stroke-width: 5; stroke-linejoin: round;">

  <svg class="fs-node STATE_INIT" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="0 0 100 100" width="50" height="50" x="167.58341363831" y="27.30474363934519">
   <g class="fs-node-group fs-router-svg" x="0px" y="0px">
<ellipse class="fs-router-background" cx="49.528" cy="47.768" rx="43.886" ry="44.768">
  <path class="fs-router-path" d="M49.528,11.366c-19.713,0-35.687,16.295-35.687,36.402c0,20.109,15.974,36.403,35.687,36.403 c19.71,0,35.685-">
  <path class="fs-router-path" d="M91.955,47.771c0,0-1.39,56.494-59.276,41.325c0,0,26.368,17.798,46.483,2.063 C87.596,84.562,100.082,71.907,91.955,47.771z">
  **<g class="fs-router-group-plus">
<ellipse class="fs-router-plus-bg" cx="22.577" cy="25.271" rx="11.926" ry="12.166">**
<line class="fs-router-plus-line" x1="22.577" y1="17.246" x2="22.577" y2="32.777">
<line class="fs-router-plus-line" x1="30.189" y1="25.271" x2="14.963" y2="25.271">
<g.....
```

I need to click on the bolded g tag. The UI is graphical. First time working on SVG elements. I am not able to locate elements. The respective attributes id, class or even index wont help it to locate. Also at UI, these elements are  dynamic based on data entered in previous screen. please help me with your inputs. Highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: doesnt `querySelector( 'g.fs-router-group-plus' )` work?

Comment: Watir is the framework. So I am not sure if querySelector could be used. I see: undefined method `querySelector' for main:Object

Comment: `querySelector()` is a DOM method and should work in pretty much any browser. I did not see, that you're using selenium, so my hint might not be useful at all.

Comment: If the id, class and index are not sufficient to help locate the element, you need to explain what is unique. As a human, how would you know which `g` element to click? Knowing that will allow you to determine how to tell Watir to find it.

Comment: What have you tried? Please list some code sample of what you have tried and the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
browser.element(:css, "g[class='fs-router-group-plus']")
```

https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-css-selectors

Comment: Watir-Webdriver v0.8.0 now supports SVG elements, so you could also do `browser.g(class: 'fs-router-group-plus')`

Comment: yes Iam using latest watir-webdriver. But click, size, find, etc doesnot work on svg, g elements